# Divinity: Original sin Boreas Treasure room

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Just how much perception is needed to see the switch to disarm all sentinel in Boreas treasure room?

I have a character with perception 11 (3 buffed from equipments). Still cant see it.

Comment: I think I only had like 9 when I did it. Are you looking in the right place?